# How to prove that $|u_{n+1} - \alpha | \le \frac{1}{2} | u_n - \alpha |$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, inequality

I'm preparing for a high school math exam and I came across this question in an old exam.

Let $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{2(1+x^3)}$.

$\alpha \in (0, \frac{1}{2})$ is the only real number such that $f(\alpha) = \alpha$.

$(u_n)$ is the series such that
$$
\begin{cases}
u_0 = 0 \\
u_{n+1} = f(u_n) \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}
\end{cases}
$$
Prove that $|u_{n+1} - \alpha| \le \frac{1}{2} |u_n - \alpha|$

The end goal is to prove that $(u_n)$ converges to $\alpha$. But we have to do it this way instead of finding that both $(u_{2n})$ and $(u_{2n+1})$ converge to $\alpha$.

It's supposed to be a very easy question. But I have been trying for the last two hours and I couldn't find it.

It's easy to prove that $u_n \in [0, \frac{1}{2}]$ by induction.

Here's what I tried:

- I tried separating the question into two cases $u_n \le \alpha$ and $u_n \ge \alpha$.
  I got that I just need to prove that $u_{n+1} + \frac{1}{2} u_n \ge \frac{3}{2} \alpha$. But I didn't know how to go from here. Substituting $u_{n+1}$ with $\dfrac{1}{2(1+u_n^3)}$ seems to only make the problem more complicated.
- I tried squaring both sides. It only made the expression more complicated.

The problem vaguely reminds me of the epsilon-delta definition of $\lim_{x \to \alpha} f(x) = \alpha$. But that seems like it won't lead anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Since $f(\alpha)=\alpha$, you are trying to prove
$$
|u_{n+1}-\alpha|\leq \frac 12|u_n-\alpha|,
$$
which is equivalent to showing
$$
|f(u_n)-f(\alpha)|\leq \frac 12|u_n-\alpha|
$$
or
$$
\frac{|f(u_n)-f(\alpha)|}{|u_n-\alpha|}\leq \frac 12
$$
By the mean value theorem, what does the left hand side equal and how can you show it is bounded above by $1/2$?

Comment: Thank you zugzug. I did not even consider using the mean value theorem. Thank you very much!

Comment: By the way, I do not consider this problem to be easy at the high school level.

Comment: Well, it depends on the curriculum I guess. This is all part of the standard curriculum in my country.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Prove that for $x,y \in \left(0,\frac12\right)$ we have
$$|f(x)-f(y)| \le \frac12 |x-y|.$$
and then apply this to $x = u_n$ and $y = \alpha$.

For example, you can use the mean value theorem since
$$f'(x) = -\frac{3x^2}{2(1+x^3)^2}$$
is strictly decreasing on $\left(0,\frac12\right)$ and $f'\left(\frac12\right) =-\frac8{27} =-0.296296.$

Comment: Thank you very much mechanodroid. The mean value theorem escaped my mind entirely. I wish I could accept this answer too but it seems I can't accept two answers. I appreciate your help! Have a good day or night!

Comment: @Oussema You can *upvote* multiple answers, that is the grey triangle above the number.

Comment: I did. But it said that my upvotes don't show up since my reputation is too low.

Answer (score 1):

We can write
$$
|u_{n+1} - \alpha| \le \frac{1}{2} |u_n - \alpha| \iff |f(u_{n}) - f(\alpha)| \le \frac{1}{2} |u_n - \alpha| 
$$
which reminds us of a famous theorem in analysis (mean value theorem). Since $f \in \mathcal{C^\infty}$, we only have to show that $\vert f' \vert \le \frac 1 2$ to apply it. But
$$
f'(x)= \frac{-3x^2}{2(1+x^3)^2}
$$
so
$$
\vert f'(x) \vert = \frac{3}{2} \left(\frac{x^2}{1+x^3}\right)^2 \le \frac{1}{2} \iff P(x)\ge0
$$
where $P(x)=\frac{x^3+1}{\sqrt{3}}-x^2$. After computing $P'$, you see that $P(x) \ge 0$. So by induction, we have
$$
|u_{n+1} - \alpha| \le \frac{1}{2} |u_n - \alpha| \le \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 |u_{n-1} - \alpha| \le \cdots \le \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+1} |u_{0} - \alpha|.
$$

Comment: Actually, if I did not miscalculate, $\frac12$ might even be replaced with $\frac13$.

Comment: Thank you Michelle. However, I'm still in high school so I can't use the theorem you're talking about. I still appreciate that you tried to help. Have a good day!

Comment: @Oussema Are you familiar with the mean value theorem?

Comment: Wait nevermind. I saw the $C^\infty$ notation which I did not understand and thought this is a different, more advanced theorem. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others, the key is to show that

> Prove that for $x,y \in \left(0,\frac12\right)$ we have
> $$|f(x)-f(y)| \le \frac12 |x-y|.$$
> and then apply this to $x = u_n$ and $y = \alpha$.

We can do so directly, without the need of calculus / MVT.

The LHS is

$$ | \frac{1}{2(1+x^3 ) } - \frac{1}{2 ( 1 + y^3) } | = \frac{1}{2} |(x-y)| \times | \frac{ x^2 + xy + y^2  } { (1+x^3 ) ( 1+y^3)}|.$$

It remains to show that the last term is $\leq 1$, which can be done in several ways like

$$x^2 + xy + y^2 \leq (x+y)^2 \leq 1 \leq ( 1 + x^3 ) ( 1+y^3 ). $$

Comment: Very nice solution! Thank you very much Calvin.